# Execute spark/Scala jar using spark-submit vs execute spark jar using java -jar

Tags: java, scala, performance, apache-spark, spark-submit

I came across with an interesting question that, the different methods of submitting the spark application from windows development environment. Generally, we submit spark job using `spark-submit` and also we can execute uber jar (dependent spark libraries assembled with jar) using `java -jar`

- Command using **java -jar:** `java -jar -Xmx1024m /home/myuser/myhar.jar`
- Command using s**park-submit:** `spark-submit --master local[*] /home/myuser/myhar.jar`

Since, I can execute the job using both method, I observed that sometimes `java -jar` method is faster and sometimes `spark-submit` is faster for same data-set (say 20000 rows with lots of data shuffling login inside).`spark-submit` has better option to control executors and memory etc using command line argument, however `java -jar`, method we need to hard-code inside the code itself. If we run the jar with large data-set `java -jar` is throwing out of memory exception while `spark-submit` is though taking time but executing without error with default configurations.

I couldn't understand the difference by submitting application using `spark-submit` and `java-jar` hence my questions is:

How the execution happen, when we submit application using `java-jar`. Does it execute inside the `jvm` memory itself and not using any spark properties?

Comment: depends upon data, if we ran spark on small chunks of data or small files, then might take longer time than normal java application. spark designed for huge data processing... On how much/size data you have tested ?

Comment: Hi Giri - thanks for your comment. Yes, spark is designed for large data set as well as small data set.  Here, mostly I am looking for significant difference between using `java -jar` and `spark-submit`!

Comment: In short, both options are equivalent. `spark-submit` is a thin wrapper around `spark-class` (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/spark-class) which in turn calls `java -jar ...` with certain JVM options, classpath, etc. usually sourced from files like `load-spark-env.sh` and `spark-defaults.conf`. If you're noticing any difference in performance, you should be able to set values in your Spark configuration files or on the command line to bring the two into line.